# error: (-215:Assertion failed) npoints >= 0 && (depth == CV_32F || depth == CV_32S) in function 'contourArea'

Tags: python, opencv

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
ret, frame=cap.read()
hsv = cv2.cvtColor(frame,cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
lower_skin = np.array([0,20,70], dtype=np.uint8)
upper_skin = np.array([20,255,255], dtype=np.uint8)
mask = cv2.inRange(hsv,lower_skin,upper_skin)
contours = cv2.findContours(mask.copy(), cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)[0]
cnt= cv2.contourArea(contours)
```

I don't know what is wrong
`error: (-215:Assertion failed) npoints >= 0 && (depth == CV_32F || depth == CV_32S) in function 'contourArea'`

Comment: You have no contours. Check the length (number of contours).

Comment: yes it has but the length is coming out to be mostly one.
do you have any idea why is it???

Comment: I suspect your lower and upper bound are not appropriate. Have you viewed your mask?

Comment: Yeah maks has got no problem.

Comment: Do you have the right index for the return items from findContours?   The number and index can be 0 or 1 depending upon your OpenCV version.

Comment: yeah i checked with all the index it is throwing same error.

Comment: post your frame. you can upload to some free hosting service and put the URL in a comment.

Comment: If you have more than one contour, you cannot get the area of them all in one command. You need to loop over each contour and get its area.

Comment: If you have only one contour or want just the first contour, then use `cnt= cv2.contourArea(contours[0])`